# Why is my modulo operator not working properly?

Tags: c++, algorithm, modulo

Given the equation y^2=x^3+2*x+4 mod 7 i want to find all possible solutions with x and y being in the range of 0 to 6. I have written the following program:

```
for  (int y=0;y<7;y++)
{
  for  (int x=0;x<7;x++)
{

    if ((x^3+5*x+4)%7==(y^2)%7)
    {

        cout<<"("<<x<<","<<y<<")"<<endl;
    }
}  
}
```

However, the output of this program is wrong. For example, the program prints out (4,1), however this does not satisfy the equation. How can i fix this?

Comment: The problem is more likely your use of the `^` operator, which is the ***bitwise XOR*** operator.

Comment: By the way, it looks like the equation in your question is not the same as the equation in your code

Comment: I'm surprised they didn't put a warning for `xor`-ing with constants, which most probably indicates programmers from other languages ...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `x^3` and `y^2` are not power operation, it is xor operation indeed, so, you can use `x*x*x` and `y*y` instead:

```
    for  (int y=0;y<7;y++)
    {
        for  (int x=0;x<7;x++)
        {

            if ((x*x*x+5*x+4)%7==(y*y)%7)
            {

                std::cout<<"("<<x<<","<<y<<")"<<std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```